# Combine parts of different tables

Tags: sql-server

Hi I'm new to sql and just needed a little help.

Say I have the following tables:

PrsDetails

```
ID  Name  Age Gen St. Co.
1   sdl   15  M   VA  US
2   slkd  14  F   TX  US
3   slkdd 17  F   VA  US
3   sldks 15  M   UP  IN
...
```

StDet

```
StateAbv  State         Reg  Co
VA        Virginia      SE   US
TX        Texas         SC   US
UP        Uttar Pradesh N    IN
...
```

CoDet

```
CountryAbv   Country         Continent
US           United States   North America
IN           India           Asia
CH           China           Asia
...
```

How would I get a new table for all people from Texas that looks like:

```
ID    Name      Age   Gen   State    Reg    Country   Continent
2     slkd      14    F     Texas    SC     US        North America
...
```

Basically, what I'm doing now is:

```
CREATE TABLE PeopleFromTexas (
ID int,
Name varChar(10),
Age int,
Gen varChar(1),
State varChar(30),
Reg varChar(4),
Country varChar(70)
Continent varChar(60)

);


INSERT INTO PeopleFromTexas
SELECT
PrsDetails.ID,
PrsDetails.Name,
PrsDetails.Age,
PrsDetails.Gen,
StDet.State,
StDet.Reg,
CoDet.Country,
CoDet.Continent

FROM
PrsDetails,
StDet,
CoDet

WHERE 
State = 'Texas'
```

But this is not working, and I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Learn about `JOIN` and use them.

Comment: ah come on tab! i was going to answer with a view :D and there is a little more to it than the join tho

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Are there any relations between all three tables?  Primary-key or foreign key? or are they just loosely in the same Schema?

Comment: @zee The ID, StateAbv, and CountryAbv are the primary keys